# Fill missing data in python list

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of lists each with a different number of elements. I'd like to add default values to the beginning of each list to make them all the same size.

So, if I start with...

```
data = {'data1': [1,2,3], 'data2': [12,23,34,45,44], 'data3': [7,8,9,10], 'data4': [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 78], 'data5': []}
```

I would like to end up with:

```
data1: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
data2: [0, 0, 12, 23, 34, 45, 44]
data3: [0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10]
data4: [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 78]
data5: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I have come up with the following code:

```
maxlen = 0
for d in data:
    if maxlen < len(data[d]):
        maxlen = len(data[d])

for d in data:
    if len(data[d]) < maxlen:
        data[d] = [0] * (maxlen - len(data[d])) + data[d]
```

This works, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could optimize the top for loop with `maxlen = max(len(i) for i in d.values())` but your second loop looks good to me (it is the same loop that would be executed if you did a dictionary comprehension). Why do you have concerns with this code?

Comment: @burhan I don't have any concerns, I was just curious to see if there were any better/smarter ways to do this.

Comment: @Peter I need to do this as I get a json feed with some metrics. Ask metrics have recent data but some may not have data for all past periods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can figure out which list is the longest, then pad out each of the other lists with zeroes in a dict comprehension.

```
>>> longest = max(len(i) for i in data.values())
>>> data = {key: [0]*(longest-len(value)) + value for key,value in data.items()}
>>> data
{'data5': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'data1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 'data4': [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 78],
 'data3': [0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 'data2': [0, 0, 12, 23, 34, 45, 44]}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.Learnt dict comprehension today :)